# Flash: What is `BitmapData.ctor`?

Tags: flash, profiling, bitmapdata

I'm profiling some Flash code, and one of the methods that's taking a lot of time is `BitmapData.ctor`. What, err, is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to create a BitmapData with invalid data you get this in your error stack:

ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData. 
at flash.display::BitmapData/ctor() 
at flash.display::BitmapData()

So - that suggests to me that ctor() is just an init() function run from the BitmapData constructor.

Answer (score 11):

It's the [constructor](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#BitmapData%28%29) of the [BitmapData](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) class.

[Constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) have the same name as their class in many languages, but these languages still have to find a way to distinguish the two symbols internally. Thus, the manifestation of `ctor` (or `.ctor`) methods that you can find neither in your code nor in the documentation.